# Find the Rusted Key at the Mines of the Betrayed's Rest

Tags: sword-art-online-hollow-fragment

I have been wandering around the `2F` of the `Graceleaf Bay Pirate Fortress` trying to open a locked door. I don't know where the key is. Where do I go to get the key for the door?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer in a forum on GameFAQs [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/734608-sword-art-online-hollow-fragment/69823661).

To sum up, you have to go to the `Tunnel of the Aspirant's Fortune` at the bottom-right corner of the map from the `2F` of the `Graceleaf Bay Pirate Fortress`. Then you need to use the hammer, `Quarry Mattock`, to break any rocks that are in your way. Follow the singular path to the `Mines of the Betrayed's Rest`. There you will find the `Rusted Key`. Lastly, trace your steps back to the locked door and open it using the key.

---

**Opinion:**
I didn't realize that the directions for the Hollow Map and the regular map are reversed for this dungeon. I also didn't realize that it was talking about the `Rusted Key` in the first place.